# В чём создавать С++ программы с интерфейсом?

Tags: c++

Допустим я хочу создать программу на С++ с интерфейсом, но я не знаком еще как это делается. Вопрос: есть ли какой либо IDE для новичков типа Visual Studio, только для Linux? Что бы мог освоить код, и понять, как там всё пишется.

Comment: Для программ с графисечким интерфейсом Qt обычно выбирают.

Comment: Скачать можно по ссылке: https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt. Кроссплатформенная среда. Позволяет работать и под Windows и под Linux

Comment: Загуглил, что то не могу разобраться как скачать, есть ли инструкция на русском как скачать на Linux?

Comment: @FormatC Увы, не могу подсказать, на Linux не работал.

Comment: Всё, уже нашел, качаю. Спасибо